# AVR in C - Storing value of register in variable

Tags: c, avr, atmega, adc

I'm using an ATmega328. I am currently doing several measurements using the 10-bit ADC. I would like to store the values it converts in variables in order to be able to operate with them. For example:

```
int a;
(...)
ADMUX = 0b01000011; //Vref = 5V, ADC3
ADCSRA |= (1<<ADSC); //Starts conversion
while(!(ADCSRA & (1<<ADIF))); //Wait until it finishes
ADCSRA |= (1<<ADIF); //Clear flag
```

Suppose that the ADC stored the value `576` in `ADCH:ADCL`. Is it possible to achieve, somehow, the variable `a` to take that same value? (i.e. `a=576;`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full 16-bit result register [should be accessible as such](http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/adc-data-registers-adcl-adch-adcw-adc):

```
a = ADC;
```

But if you want to read both parts manually, then

```
a = ADCL;
a |= ADCH << 8;
```

That has to be done in two separate statements to force `ADCH` to be read last. The I/O modules have a temporary register to hold the high byte, preventing the module itself from corrupting the read value if it changes the value of the register. (i.e. if the ADC finishes another conversion and stores the new value.)

If you have interrupts that access the ADC (or need to use the value at `a`), you'll need to disable them for the duration of the access (that also goes for `a = ADC`, since it also compiles into multiple 8-bit reads).

Comment: This is susceptible to corruption.  See answer that follows.

Comment: @JLH, point. Though note that the text in the application note goes "If the interrupt function accesses the same resources the access must be made an atomic operation". If there are no interrupts that access the ADC, there's no problem.

Comment: From the OP's code it's not clear if another ADC -- or anything else -- could kick off while this one is being stored.  Better safe than sorry.

Comment: @JLH, (I'm not sure what you mean with "another ADC", a conversion, or a converter.) It doesn't matter if another A/D conversion happens when reading ADCL+ADCH, that's what the temp register is for. And disabling interrupts would do nothing to prevent the ADC from running, either.

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is close, still comes up a little short based on the recommendations from the chip manufacturer.  To be safe you should follow the instructions in the authoritative reference linked below.

Simply turn off interrupts just before and restore them after:

```
unsigned int a; // 16-bit word
// other code
cli();
a = ADCL;
a |= ADCH << 8;
sei();
```

Every example in this reference *from the chip manufacturer* follows this pattern for atomic 16-bit reads and writes.  Reference: [AVR Application Note 072](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc1493.pdf).

Comment: *Another ADC measurement* can't happen - Once you read `ADCL` the AVR locks the ADC register against changes from the ADC until you have also read ADCH. See the manual. Why an interrupt service routine should be able to corrupt the `a` value unless it writes to it escapes me at the moment. It should, however, not try to *use* the half-updated `a` value.

Comment: @tofro True enough as far as it goes, but unless we see **all** of the OP's code we cannot know what else might be going on.  I have never, ever gone wrong following the instructions in AVR072.